# Fetching Mustache array in javascript

Tags: javascript, mustache

Is it possible to pass a Mustache array to a JavaScript array? For example if I have a Mustache array I can show the values in html using for example:

```
{{#contents}}
      <tr>
      {{#show}}
      <td>{{title}}</td><td>{{body}}</td>
      {{/show}}
      </tr>
{{/contents}}
```

But is it also possible to so something like:

```
<script>
result = [];
result = {{contents}};
</script>
```

in JavaScript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can compile mustache templates to javascript functions, but `result = {{contents}};` will cause a javascript error.  Depending on what you are hoping to achieve, you might want to use template partials.